# Unable to access list in vf page

Tags: apex

I have a custom setting from which I queried certain fields using below query and assigned it to List.

```
List<Hierarchy_Object__c> objList = [SELECT TYPEOF SetupOwner
                                            WHEN Profile THEN Id, Name
                                            END, Discount__c, Price__c
                                            FROM Hierarchy_Object__c
                                            WHERE SetupOwnerId IN (Select Id FROM Profile)];
```

I am trying to access the list using VF page but VF page didn't show any vales...

```
<apex:page controller="CustomSettingsClass">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Profiles">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!objList}" var="li">
                    <apex:column value="{!li.SetupOwner.Name}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!li.Discount__c}"/>
                     <apex:column value="{!li.Price__c}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton value="Get Profiles" action="{!settingsClass}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Can someone help me what I have missed in Vf page...

Comment: Just to confirm, do you have data in the custom settings ? if not already done, add a system.debug in apex method to log results of `objList` to check this

Comment: I found the error and  I am getting values onto the page... Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good to know. You can post an answer describing what was the issue and how you fixed it, this will help the community